# Set legend width to be 100% plot width

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I set the legend height or width to be 100% of the plot height/width regardless of the actual dimensions?

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, color=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.position="bottom",
    legend.key.width=unit(0.1,"npc"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.5   2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I know of is to manually adjust the grid objects in the gtable of the plot. AFAIK, the guides are mostly defined in cm (rather than relative units), so getting them adapted to the panels is a bit of a pain. I'd also love to know a better way to do this.

```r
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, color=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.position="bottom",
    legend.key.width=unit(0.1,"npc"),
    legend.margin = margin(), # pre-emptively set zero margins
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"))

gt <- ggplotGrob(g) 

# Extract legend
is_legend <- which(gt$layout$name == "guide-box")
legend <- gt$grobs[is_legend][[1]]
legend <- legend$grobs[legend$layout$name == "guides"][[1]]

# Set widths in guide gtable
width <- as.numeric(legend$widths[4]) # save bar width (assumes 'cm' unit) 
legend$widths[4] <- unit(1, "null") # replace bar width

# Set width/x of bar/labels/ticks. Assumes everything is 'cm' unit.
legend$grobs[[2]]$width <- unit(1, "npc")
legend$grobs[[3]]$children[[1]]$x <- unit(
  as.numeric(legend$grobs[[3]]$children[[1]]$x) / width, "npc"
)
legend$grobs[[5]]$x0 <- unit(as.numeric(legend$grobs[[5]]$x0) / width, "npc")
legend$grobs[[5]]$x1 <- unit(as.numeric(legend$grobs[[5]]$x1) / width, "npc")

# Replace legend
gt$grobs[[is_legend]] <- legend

# Draw new plot
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Please forgive me for double answers, but I believe this to be a totally different approach, and the credits for the idea go to @benson23.

We can use `ggh4x::force_panelsizes()` to set an absolute size for the panel and match the width of the bar. Upside is that it is reasonably easy to do, downside is that your plot's width doesn't automagically adapts to the window size anymore.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

width <- unit(10, "cm")

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, color=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point() +
  guides(colour = guide_colorbar(barwidth = width)) +
  force_panelsizes(cols = width) +
  theme(
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.position="bottom",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"))
```

[image]

The process becomes slightly more complicated if a plot has multiple panels, but it is not undoable.

```r
ncol         <- 3
total_width  <- unit(10, "cm")
# Optionally: replace `theme_get()` with actual theme you're using
spacing      <- calc_element("panel.spacing.x", theme_get())
panel_widths <- (total_width - spacing * (ncol - 1)) / ncol

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, color=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point() +
  guides(colour = guide_colorbar(barwidth = total_width)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, ncol = ncol) +
  force_panelsizes(cols = panel_widths) +
  theme(
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.position="bottom",
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Disclaimer: I'm the author of {ggh4x}

Comment: For this to work, we don't actually need `theme(legend.key.width, legend.margin, legend.spacing.x)`?

Comment: Yeah you're right about the first two. You get a slight misalignment if you omit `legend.spacing.x` as there is a tiny space reserved that is normally used to place the title of the legend at a small distance from the legend itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll use a very manual way to set the legend width, which is `guides(colour = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 25))`. Just try out the `barwidth` parameter, you'll get one that fits the plot.

I'd also love to know a way to easily get the width of the plot, so that we don't need to manually set the `barwidth`.

**UPDATE: As you can see in the comment under this answer, both @teunbrand and I agree that we can use a `barwidth` value close to the value of `fig.width` in `Rmarkdown` or `width` in `ggsave` if you are using these utilities to display your graph**

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, color=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  guides(colour = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 25)) +
  theme(
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.position="bottom")
```

[image: legend_barwidth]

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way to know the width of the panel until the plot is drawn. The panel width is defined in relative units ('null' units at the grid level), so that it adapts to a new plotting window whenever it is resized. Roughly speaking, the panel size is whatever is left of the plotting window after reserving space for margins and plot decorations (axes, titles, etc).

Comment: What about we kind of hack it to use `barwidth` similar to the value in `fig.width` in `Rmarkdown` or `width` in `ggsave`, so that we can kind of manually sets the width of "plot", which will be very similar to the width of the "panel"?

Comment: That is a pretty good idea! I know of a way to do this with reasonable elegance, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted @teunbrand's ggplotGrob answer to work as a function. Added `ggplotify` to convert gtable back to ggplot. Note that it only works specifically for horizontal colorbars.

**Original plot**:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotify)

g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, color=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
g
```

[image]

**Plot with full width colorbar legend**:

```r
#' @param x A ggplot object with colorbar legend along the width.
#'
full_width_legend <- function(x){
  gt <- ggplotGrob(x)
  
  # Extract legend
  is_legend <- which(gt$layout$name == "guide-box")
  legend <- gt$grobs[is_legend][[1]]
  legend <- legend$grobs[legend$layout$name == "guides"][[1]]
  
  # Set widths in guide gtable
  width <- as.numeric(legend$widths[4]) # save bar width (assumes 'cm' unit) 
  legend$widths[4] <- unit(1, "null") # replace bar width
  
  # Set width/x of bar/labels/ticks. Assumes everything is 'cm' unit.
  legend$grobs[[2]]$width <- unit(1, "npc")
  legend$grobs[[3]]$children[[1]]$x <- unit(
    as.numeric(legend$grobs[[3]]$children[[1]]$x) / width, "npc"
  )
  legend$grobs[[5]]$x0 <- unit(as.numeric(legend$grobs[[5]]$x0) / width, "npc")
  legend$grobs[[5]]$x1 <- unit(as.numeric(legend$grobs[[5]]$x1) / width, "npc")
  
  # Replace legend
  gt$grobs[[is_legend]] <- legend
  return(ggplotify::as.ggplot(gt))
}

g1 <- full_width_legend(g)
g1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>