# Set legend width to be 100% plot width with categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

Similar to [Set legend width to be 100% plot width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073338/set-legend-width-to-be-100-plot-width), I am trying to obtain a plot where the legend with discrete categories uses 100% of the width space. However, the labels are placed incorrectly.

Is there a way to use 100% of the horizonal width for any plot? (i.e. without knowing if the width is 10 cm, 5 in, etc beforehand)

MWE

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = as.factor(am)))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.position="bottom",
    legend.key.width=unit(0.1,"npc"),
    legend.margin = margin(), # pre-emptively set zero margins
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"))

gt <- ggplotGrob(g) 

# Extract legend
is_legend <- which(gt$layout$name == "guide-box")
legend <- gt$grobs[is_legend][[1]]
legend <- legend$grobs[legend$layout$name == "guides"][[1]]

# Set widths in guide gtable
width <- as.numeric(legend$widths[4]) # save bar width (assumes 'cm' unit) 
legend$widths[4] <- unit(1, "null") # replace bar width

# Set width/x of bar/labels/ticks. Assumes everything is 'cm' unit.
legend$grobs[[2]]$width <- unit(1, "npc")
legend$grobs[[3]]$children[[1]]$x <- unit(
  as.numeric(legend$grobs[[3]]$children[[1]]$x) / width, "npc"
)
legend$grobs[[5]]$x0 <- unit(as.numeric(legend$grobs[[5]]$x0) / width, "npc")
legend$grobs[[5]]$x1 <- unit(as.numeric(legend$grobs[[5]]$x1) / width, "npc")

# Replace legend
gt$grobs[[is_legend]] <- legend

# Draw new plot
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(gt)
```

[image: mwe with bad centering]

Answer (score 3):

We might fake it with two plots combined with `patchwork`, which solves the challenging task of aligning the plot range of multiple plots.

```
library(patchwork); library(dplyr)
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color = as.factor(am)))+
  geom_point()+
  guides(color = "none")

l <- ggplot(mtcars %>% distinct(am), 
            aes(as.factor(am), 1,  label = am)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_text(hjust = -1) +
  guides(color = "none") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())

g / l + plot_layout(heights = c(20,1))
```

[image]

Comment: powerful answer! I'll try to put this inside a function