# Set legend width to be 100% plot width for any geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

Similar to [Set legend width to be 100% plot width with categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480996/set-legend-width-to-be-100-plot-width-with-categories/72481154#72481154) and [Set legend width to be 100% plot width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073338/set-legend-width-to-be-100-plot-width?noredirect=1&lq=1), I am trying to expand the legend width.

For example, for this plot

```
ggplot(gapminder2007) +
  geom_col(aes(x = country, y = lifeExp, fill = continent), position = "dodge") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"))
```

I want to obtain the next result (edited with Inkscape)
[image]

I've tried the solutions from the links, which are to use `units()` and `patchwork` respectively, but those doesn't work with `geom_col` and return the next distorted legend
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This one is from one of the mentioned so pages [Set legend width to be 100% plot width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073338/set-legend-width-to-be-100-plot-width?noredirect=1&lq=1) using the `ggh4x` written by @teunbrand:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)
library(ggh4x)

width <- unit(12, "cm")

gapminder2007 <- gapminder %>% 
  filter(year == 2007)
ggplot(gapminder2007) +
  geom_col(aes(x = country, y = lifeExp, fill = continent), position = "dodge") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"))+
  guides(color = guide_colorbar(barwidth = width)) +
  force_panelsizes(cols = width)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, and I have two main problems
1. Inside a function, it work work
2. With ggsave, the width is unaltered

Answer (score 1):

The legend.margin argument allows you to edit the size of the legend using the `margin` function

```
library(gapminder)

ggplot(gapminder |> 
         filter(continent %in% c("Americas", "Europe"), country %in% c("Chile", "Spain"))) +
  geom_col(aes(x = country, y = lifeExp, fill = continent), position = "dodge") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"),
        legend.margin = margin(0,6,0,6, "cm"))
```

[image]